# How can I change the target dataset dynamically based on the file path location in the project?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

Is there a way to change the target dataset on BigQuery based on the file path location with dbt?

For example:

project
models
contextA
contextB

There are two datasets on BigQuery: datasetA and datasetB

I would like to save the models inside folder **contextA** in the dataset called **datasetA** and the ones inside **contextB** in the dataset **contextB** dynamically, **without considering the target in profiles.yml**.

I've tried to do it with that macro called **generate_alias_name**, but without success.

Comment: You can do this in `dbt_project.yml`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `dbt_project.yml`. In the models folder, you will have folders `contextA` and `contextB`. Then in `dbt_project.yml`, you will add this:

```
models:
  project_name:
    contextA:    
      schema: datasetA
    contextB:
      schema: datasetB
```

You can do this even with nested folders:

```
    contextA:    
      schema: datasetA
      another_folder_in_contextA_that_saves_models_to_a_different_dataset:
        schema: another_dataset
    contextB:
      schema: datasetB
```